Please help me with the title of this movie. I don't seem to remember it. Watched it years ago
Really long ago I watched a movie but I don't seem to recollect the name of the movie or the actress. 
It was about this woman who could kind of see whats going to happen a few days later. In the movie she wakes up on a Saturday and realises that yesterday was a Tuesday, she is confused but goes ahead with her day but meets with an accident the same day and then she wakes up on a Wednesday and realises nothing happened.
Its like she has lived an episode of her future. And now she knows how she is dying the following Saturday. The plot is something like this. 

Welcome to Movies & TV! We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title

@Jiya Khan Posted a possible match, but it would be better if you posted as many details about the movie as you can.

Sounds like Premonition

Depressed housewife learns her husband was killed in a car accident the day previously, awakens the next morning to find him alive and well at home, and then awakens the next day after to a world in which he is still dead. 




